# Pakyow App Redis Error

Tags: redis, pakyow

While working through the Pakyow ["warmup" tutorial](https://www.pakyow.org/docs/warmup), I encountered the error
`Redis::CannotConnectError`. I'm on macOS and installed Redis via homebrew. Do I perhaps need to start a Redis server manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep redis needs to be running. Just run [`redis-server`](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart#starting-redis) from the command line and you should be good to go!